# How to get connection with particular server in j2me application 

Tags: eclipse, mobile, java-me, sms, nokia

I am beginner of j2me application. I am working on application of tracking the mobile. I am supposed to make application in j2me is like I can save the received SMS in some nokia mobile in some server and then fetch that sms and send that message to another mobile device.

I am using Eclipse IDE for this application.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can read SMS from inbox. for this purpose  you need to use `APIBridge.jar` file. just google & download. This file fills the gap between Java ME & Phone's Native Operating system. Using this JAR File you can perform many other native things. You will find its example with that JAR File.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sending sms on some predefine port no and your j2me application is listening on that port then and only then you can get those message.

Reading sms from **inbox** is **not possible with j2me**.